# MYSQL Query for pending `Purchase Order`

Tags: mysql, database

how to query to database in order get pending po list.

I have four table `purchase_order` with this fields

```
`po_id` // primary key
`supplier_id`
'date`
`status`
'description`

`po_detail` with this fields
`pod_id` // primary key
`po_id`
`product_id`
`rate`
`qty`

`grn` with this fields
`grn_id` // primary key
`date`
`description`
`supplier_id`

`grn_detail` with this fields
`grnd_id` // primary key
`grn_id`
`rate`
`qty`
`product_id`
`po_id`
```

now i am to select all product from po_detail which is not entered in `grn_detail` with that `po_id` OR entered into `grn_detail` but `grn_detail.qty` is **<** `po_detail.qty` with same po_id
could you please write the query.
if possile please write with demo in sqlfiddle

please have look in [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86cb0)

Comment: It will be much better if you create your own SQLFiddle with some sample data and with the query that you have tried

Comment: i must say i spend at least 50% of my time doing what the op should have done in the question during setup. So basically what @Crazy2crack just said

Comment: I do not understand why the people who ask question do not create SQLfiddle in the first place, and expect people who will answer the question to spend time on it just to help them. No offence @Humaira Naaz. I am speaking in general sense.

Comment: need to make the question more absolute.need table names and relationship, on what are you querying to database? do you use any server side language like php, asp etc to query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first answer is quite well but i think there may little changes in operator.
something like that **>=**

[**SEE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86cb0/6)

```
SELECT * FROM `po_detail`
WHERE
  `po_detail`.`po_id` NOT IN
    (SELECT `grn_detail`.`po_id` FROM `grn_detail`
     WHERE (`grn_detail`.`po_id` <> `po_detail`.`po_id`) OR
       (`grn_detail`.`qty` >= `po_detail`.`qty`))
AND your_other_filter_if_you_want_to
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `po_detail`
WHERE
  `po_detail`.`po_id` NOT IN
    (SELECT `grn_detail`.`po_id` FROM `grn_detail`
     WHERE (`grn_detail`.`po_id` <> `po_detail`.`po_id`) OR
           (`grn_detail`.`qty` > `po_detail`.`qty`))
```